Event Log API for getting the Opportunities created and modified
Is there any way i Can get a list of users who have created or modified any Standard object like Opportunities or Accounts and Custom Objects through the Event log API? The List of events given in the API documentation for Event Log API does not seem to indicate any Object type events that can be reported. Can there be any other way to get that data along with their timestamp?

Hi, thanks for your question. Just to clarify, are you looking for admin level changes to the actual objects themselves, or changes to records within those objects?
